# (Selenium) - Not able to find the suggestor locator on Flikart?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation, flipkart-api

On Flipkart site - https://www.flipkart.com/

I am entering "laptop" in the Search Bar

[image]

Now I want to click on the fifth suggestion whatever it is, here in this case it is laptop table.

How can I find it's xpath (locator) as on opening the console - suggestor gets closes automatically?

Comment: In the web we usually used the debugger stop, this option is available in the console section.

Comment: Edit your question and share your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared your code trials nor you have mentioned which programming language you use, I assume it is PYTHON.

Below is the XPath expression which should work for you:

```
//form[@method='GET']//ul//li[5]
```

Note: `[5]` - refers to fifth dropdown suggestion item

**Working code in Python:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Below line will click on the inital login pop-up's X button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@role='button']"))).click()
# Below line will enter 'laptop' in the desired text box
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("laptop")
# Below line will click the 5th dropdown suggestion item
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@method='GET']//ul//li[5]"))).click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, when exploring the Flipkart search bar, you may observe that the suggestions automatically close, posing a challenge when working with XPath.

**Here's a useful tip**: After inspecting the element, navigate to the Event Listener. By removing any actions associated with the '[blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpTQc.png)' event, you can maintain the visibility of suggestions. This approach simplifies the inspection process and allows for the derivation of XPath expressions for further analysis.

Here is the Python code that I have implemented to fulfill this objective:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@role='button']"))).click() # This is to close the intial pop up
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@class='Pke_EE']"))).send_keys("laptop")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='_1sFryS _2x2Mmc _3ofZy1']//li[5]"))).click()
time.sleep(10)
```

If you wish to perform a hands-on test, I have created a test case using **Test Assist, a no-code Selenium editor**. I invite you to review and execute the test case by clicking on the following link:
https://app.testassist.dev/program/0f294743-0241-4149-bbae-a2d1d65a8fc4